# Calling a C style DLL succeeds and then AutoIt crashes

Tags: c, dll, autoit

I'm trying to call a C style library called "universal speech" from AutoIt 3 (latest version). I get the desired action from the function I'm calling but after I get the response AutoIt crashes saying "AutoIt has stopped working, Windows can search for the solution..." Am I doing something wrong?

AutoIt:

```
#notrayicon
dllcall("UniversalSpeech.dll", "int", "speechSayA", "str", "test 123", "int", 1)
sleep(1000)
```

universal speech.h:

```
#ifndef ____UNIVERSAL_SPEECH_H__
#define ____UNIVERSAL_SPEECH_H__
#if defined __WIN32 || defined __WIN64
#define export __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#error Platform currently unsupported
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int export speechSayA (const char* str, int interrupt) ;
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
#endif
```

I successfully did this in other programming languages but AutoIt doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" to a question. You did the right thing by *answering* (and, given some time, you can accept it).

Answer (score 3):

"binhnx" on AutoIt forum solved my problem:

This library uses the `cdecl` calling convention and AutoIt by default uses the `stdcall` calling convention. Cdecl is supported, though you have to tell AutoIt that you want to use it by entering `:cdecl` next to the return type of the function you're calling.

So in my case instead of:

```
dllcall("UniversalSpeech.dll", "int"...)
```

you'd go like this:

```
dllcall("UniversalSpeech.dll", "int:cdecl"...)
```

Which solves the crash.

Comment: "I think autoit devs should make it so autoit switches automatically the methods" How should it do so? It has no means for finding out which is the correct one...

Comment: In theory it could be possible by saving the stack pointer and comparing it after returning from the dll function.